# defaultGrailsBootstrapClass NPE during :bootRun

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

1. Using IntelliJ Ultimate, latest version, running on Arch Linux
2. Had built an app over the last two years using Grails 3.1.1
3. Upgraded to 3.2.2 recently
4. No longer able to use 'run-app' due to unresolvable :profile
5. Able to right-click and debug Application.main(), continued working
6. Ready to run 'war', realize same problem with 'run-app' (unresolvable :profile)
7. Merge code into fresh Grails project in IntelliJ
8. Continue to get same error trying to run-app

```
    > Building 85% > :bootRun2016-11-14 23:34:22.969 ERROR --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
    > Building 85% > :bootRun
    java.lang.NullPointerException: null
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.CurriedClosure.(CurriedClosure.java:58)
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.CurriedClosure.(CurriedClosure.java:84)
            at groovy.lang.Closure.curry(Closure.java:534)
            at org.grails.web.servlet.boostrap.DefaultGrailsBootstrapClass.callInit(DefaultGrailsBootstrapClass.java:61)
            at org.grails.web.servlet.context.GrailsConfigUtils.executeGrailsBootstraps(GrailsConfigUtils.java:65)
            at org.grails.plugins.web.servlet.context.BootStrapClassRunner.onStartup(BootStrapClassRunner.groovy:53)
            at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:256)
            at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy)
            at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:166)
            at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:382)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:336)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
            at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544)
            at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
            at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:83)
            at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:387)
            at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:374)
            at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
            at my_app.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)
```

Comment: Pastebin of entire stacktrace from IntelliJ console:
http://pastebin.ca/3739055

Comment: running 'grails war' will successfully build a war file, but 'run-app' still will not launch the app locally

Comment: also, the app is able to write to the database, so that portion is functioning without issue

Comment: The bootstrap was moved to be under a package name now in 3.2.2.

Comment: Yep, my bootstrap is under a package name; still gives me an issue. It parses the bootstrap.groovy file just fine, as I can see it executing through all my breaks in debug mode. Its something well past when it parses through my bootstrap, and that's what I can't figure out. This feels like a bug in Grails but I was surprised I'd be the only one to have found it.

Comment: Figured it out: I had moved the logic used to build out my various environments at boot time into their own classes. Unfortunately, in this case, Grails' usage of searching by class name for a convention based string, such as in this case, any class with "BootStrap" in the name, caused it to load my BootStrap class as well as my subsequent BootStrapPROD and BootStrapDEV classes. This also happened when I moved them into a different sub package and even into a different package altogether. Removing the BootStrap portion from the name resolved it. Quite a misleading stacktrace...